# Infinite Recursion loop C

Tags: c, recursion

We have been learning about recursion vs iteration in C this week and we were required to make a program that recursively determines the value of the nth term of a geometric sequence defined by the terms a, ar, ar^2, ... ar^(n-q).
For the most part, I think I have it figured out, as it seems to display the correct values per run, but it doesn't manage to break the recursion when the tested value reaches zero. Also, if possible to get a better explanation of recursion, and some examples of when recursion would be preferred over iteration as I'm still struggling with the concept.
    // 2/20/2018
    //Lab 6 Solution for Page 369 PE 4 B

```
//including libraries to be used
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    //Function prototype
    double goAnswer(int *, double, double, double, double *, int);

    //Declaring variables
    int nValue = 0;
    double ratio = 0;
    double firstTerm = 0;
    double answer = 0;
    double addedAnswer = 0;
    int count = 1;

    //Setting up to ask for each value
    printf("Please enter in the value of n: ");
    scanf("%d", &nValue);
    printf("Please enter in the ratio you'd like to use: ");
    scanf("%lf", &ratio);
    printf("Please enter in the first term to use: ");
    scanf("%lf", &firstTerm);
    addedAnswer = goAnswer(&nValue, ratio, firstTerm, answer, &addedAnswer, 
count);

    //Printing out the value of the first nth terms
    printf("The value of all terms added together is: %lf\n", addedAnswer);

    return 0;
}

//function header
double goAnswer(int *nValue, double ratio, double firstTerm, double answer, 
double *addedAnswer, int count) {

    if (nValue == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else{ //This part calculates the answer, prints the value to the screen, 
adds the answer to a running sum, decreases the nValue by one and calls the 
function again with the lower nValue
        answer = firstTerm * pow(ratio, count);
        printf("The value of term %d is: %lf\n", count, answer);
        printf("This is the nValue: %d \n", *nValue);
        *addedAnswer += answer;
        nValue -= 1;
        return (goAnswer(nValue, ratio, firstTerm, answer, addedAnswer, 
(count + 1)));
    }

}
```

Comment: Every `nvalue` access would be `*nvalue` in the func.

Comment: I thought I needed it to be able to pass by reference so it could change the variable outside the initially called function.

Comment: `nValue` isn't a reference, it's a pointer. Inside your function `nValue` is the pointer address.  `*nValue` is the actual value you want to work with.

Comment: I see what you are saying. It now displays the propper nValue, but it still isn't stopping the recursions when nValue = 0

Comment: Did you change `nValue -= 1;` as well? It has to be `*nValue -= 1;`. (`--*nValue;` would work as well.) Please, note that the former is syntactically correct (decrements pointer `nValue`) but surely not intended by you.

Comment: Actually, it is not necessary to make parameter `nValue` of type `int*`. Your above code would work with parameter `int nValue` and the rest non-modified (with the only necessary modification in `main()`: `addedAnswer = goAnswer(nValue, ratio, firstTerm, answer, &addedAnswer, count);`).

Comment: I have done what you said and you are correct. Could you explain to me a bit more about why I don't have to set the type to int*?

Comment: It's not necessary to pass the address of `nValue` in `main()` - its value is fully sufficient. Each (recursive) call gets the value and (if not yet 0) has to call itself with `nValue - 1`. (Decrementing `nValue` before using it as argument provides the same.) Of course, each call of `goAnswer()` has its own copy of `nValue` but this isn't a problem. This kind of recursion termination is actually quite common. You probably find samples by google - often this param. is called `depth` as its init. value (decremented in each call of rec. function until 0) determines precisely the recursion depth.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.